# Debian package set keep old conffile - not over apt globally

Tags: debian, apt, packages, dpkg

I want to update a own debian-package on different servers.
I would like to keep the old conf file, if it exists and not to say always no if prompt is asking what I want to do : 
*The default action is to keep your current version. 

*** bash.bashrc (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?* 
I don't want to set in apt.conf or apt install command something like `Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"`
So only to define it in the specific package.

Could only find the **Dpkg:Options** solutions. Or is it something to script at **postinst** ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the apt option on the command line which you run to install the package:

```
apt-get install -o Dpkg::Options=--force-confold <package>
```